# aurelia-bootstrapper not found after upgrading to jspm beta

Tags: aurelia, jspm, systemjs

I've upgrade to the latest JSPM

```
sudo npm install -g jspm@beta
```

And reinstalled all packages by deleting the `jspm_modules` folder and running

```
jspm install
jspm dl-loader
```

Now when I start my Aurelia project, I get the following output

```
GET http://localhost:9000/dist/app/github:aurelia/bootstrapper@0.15.0.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried deleting my `config.js` map configuration and having jspm rebuild it

```
System.config({
  "defaultJSExtensions": true,
  "transpiler": "babel",
  "babelOptions": {
    "optional": [
      "runtime"
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "*": "dist/*"
  }
});

System.config({
  "map": {
    "aurelia-animator-css": "github:aurelia/animator-css@0.14.1",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "github:aurelia/bootstrapper@0.15.0",
    "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework@0.14.0",
    "aurelia-http-client": "github:aurelia/http-client@0.10.2",
    "aurelia-router": "github:aurelia/router@0.10.4",
    "aurelia-task-queue": "github:aurelia/task-queue@0.6.1",
    "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.21",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.20",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18",
    "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.13",
    "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4",
    "jssha": "npm:jssha@1.6.1",
    "materialize": "github:dogfalo/materialize@0.97.0",
    "moment": "github:moment/moment@2.10.6",
    "numeral": "npm:numeral@1.5.3",
    "github:aurelia/animator-css@0.14.1": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2",
      "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16"
    },
    "github:aurelia/binding@0.8.5": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "github:aurelia/task-queue@0.6.1",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/bootstrapper@0.15.0": {
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "github:aurelia/event-aggregator@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework@0.14.0",
      "aurelia-history": "github:aurelia/history@0.6.1",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "github:aurelia/history-browser@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "github:aurelia/loader-default@0.9.3",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "github:aurelia/logging-console@0.6.1",
      "aurelia-router": "github:aurelia/router@0.10.4",
      "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "github:aurelia/templating-binding@0.13.2",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "github:aurelia/templating-resources@0.13.4",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "github:aurelia/templating-router@0.14.1",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1": {
      "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/event-aggregator@0.6.2": {
      "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.6.2"
    },
    "github:aurelia/framework@0.14.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "github:aurelia/binding@0.8.5",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1",
      "aurelia-loader": "github:aurelia/loader@0.8.3",
      "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2",
      "aurelia-path": "github:aurelia/path@0.8.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "github:aurelia/task-queue@0.6.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/history-browser@0.6.2": {
      "aurelia-history": "github:aurelia/history@0.6.1",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/http-client@0.10.2": {
      "aurelia-path": "github:aurelia/path@0.8.1",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/loader-default@0.9.3": {
      "aurelia-loader": "github:aurelia/loader@0.8.3",
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2"
    },
    "github:aurelia/loader@0.8.3": {
      "aurelia-html-template-element": "github:aurelia/html-template-element@0.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2",
      "aurelia-path": "github:aurelia/path@0.8.1",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18",
      "webcomponentsjs": "github:webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@0.6.3"
    },
    "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2": {
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/route-recognizer@0.6.1": {
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/router@0.10.4": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1",
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "github:aurelia/event-aggregator@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-history": "github:aurelia/history@0.6.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-path": "github:aurelia/path@0.8.1",
      "aurelia-route-recognizer": "github:aurelia/route-recognizer@0.6.1",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/templating-binding@0.13.2": {
      "aurelia-binding": "github:aurelia/binding@0.8.5",
      "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16"
    },
    "github:aurelia/templating-resources@0.13.4": {
      "aurelia-binding": "github:aurelia/binding@0.8.5",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "github:aurelia/task-queue@0.6.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:aurelia/templating-router@0.14.1": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2",
      "aurelia-path": "github:aurelia/path@0.8.1",
      "aurelia-router": "github:aurelia/router@0.10.4",
      "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16"
    },
    "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.16": {
      "aurelia-binding": "github:aurelia/binding@0.8.5",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "github:aurelia/dependency-injection@0.9.1",
      "aurelia-html-template-element": "github:aurelia/html-template-element@0.2.0",
      "aurelia-loader": "github:aurelia/loader@0.8.3",
      "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.6.2",
      "aurelia-metadata": "github:aurelia/metadata@0.7.2",
      "aurelia-path": "github:aurelia/path@0.8.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "github:aurelia/task-queue@0.6.1",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
    },
    "github:dogfalo/materialize@0.97.0": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.13",
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.10.1"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.20": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1"
    },
    "npm:core-js@0.9.18": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:numeral@1.5.3": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2"
    }
  }
});
```

However, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the problem is in the config.js. The paths are traversed in reverse, it seems, and so changing the paths to the following resolves the issue:

```
"paths": {
  "*": "dist/*",
  "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
  "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"  
}
```

Resolves the issue.

Comment: I am really curious why this would make a difference.